# Summary from lme() output returning estimate value of 0?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to run a linear mixed effects model using the `nlme` package using the lme() function with the `txhousing` data from the `ggplot2` package in R. When I run the following model I get that some of the fixed effects estimates are zero. What can I do to remedy this?

[Model Summary Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m683m.jpg)

I'm specifying the following model using variables from `txhousing`:
 `fit1 <- lme(fixed = median ~ date + volume + listings + sales + inventory, random = ~ 1 | city, data = txhousing, method = "ML")`

I have not transformed any of the variables.

I've tried running separate lm() fits of `lm(median ~ volume, txhousing)` and `lm(median ~ sales, txhousing)` to see what the estimates are and they were not zero in these models.

Comment: That a simpler model has non-zero effects isn't much evidence that a more complex model should have non-zero effects. At the very least, run the same fixed effects terms in `lm` to see if those terms are close to 0... `lm(median ~ date + volume + listings + sales + inventory,  data = txhousing)`

Comment: *"I have not transformed any of the variables."* That could also be your problem. If you're not transforming, the coefficients are in the units of your data. If volume and listings are on a drastically different scale than your other variables they might not be easily comparable. Like, if you included house area measured in square cm, that would have a tiny coefficient because a 1 cm^2 increase in house size will have a negligible effect on the price. But if you included area in acres, that would have a huge effect because a 1 acre bigger house would have a massive effect.

Comment: @GregorThomas I ran the lm() model that you specified and it returned estimates for volume of 1.461e-04 with p-value < 2e-16 and estimates for listings of 1.085 with p-value 9.95e-11

Comment: Yeah, so 0.000461 is pretty much 0, and the 1.085 is also small. If you look directly at `fixef(fit1)` (can't remember if that's the `nlme` syntax or just the `lme4` syntax...) you may be able to easily see your coefficients with more decimal places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@GregorThomas's conclusion is exactly correct; this is a scaling problem.

```r
data("txhousing", package = "ggplot2")
library(nlme)

fit1 <- lme(fixed = median ~ date + volume + listings + sales + inventory,
            random = ~ 1 | city, data = txhousing, method = "ML",
            na.action = na.omit,
            ## avoid warning from nlminb
            control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"))
```

If you want to see the full range of values, try `fixef(fit1)`:

```
  (Intercept)          date        volume      listings         sales 
-7.582129e+06  3.839669e+03  5.924324e-05 -1.806455e-01 -4.667077e+00 
    inventory 
-3.419350e+02
```

The intercept is enormous because the mean values of the covariates are far from zero; the other coefficients vary by orders of magnitude because the units/ranges are very different.

We can refit after standardizing (centering and scaling) all the numeric variables (including the response variable, as suggested by Schielzeth (2010)):

```r
nvars <- c("date", "volume", "listings", "sales", "inventory", "median")
txhousing_sc <- txhousing
txhousing_sc[nvars] <- scale(txhousing_sc[nvars])

fit2 <- update(fit1, data = txhousing_sc)
printCoefmat(coef(summary(fit2)))
```

```
printCoefmat(coef(summary(fit2)), digits = 3)
                Value Std.Error        DF t-value p-value    
(Intercept) -1.16e-02  1.06e-01  7.08e+03   -0.11   0.913    
date         4.62e-01  4.68e-03  7.08e+03   98.71 < 2e-16 ***
volume       3.88e-01  3.05e-02  7.08e+03   12.75 < 2e-16 ***
listings    -2.89e-02  1.58e-02  7.08e+03   -1.83   0.068 .  
sales       -1.39e-01  4.23e-02  7.08e+03   -3.28   0.001 ** 
inventory   -4.22e-02  8.70e-03  7.08e+03   -4.85 1.3e-06 ***
```

Schielzeth, Holger. 2010. “Simple Means to Improve the Interpretability of Regression Coefficients: Interpretation of Regression Coefficients.” Methods in Ecology and Evolution 1 (2): 103–13. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00012.x.

Comment: Thanks so much this makes sense! Thanks to @GregorThomas too!